# XSL-FO Reverted text in footnote

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to display correctly a footnote inside a PDF with Apache FOP.

```
<fo:block text-align="right">
    <fo:bidi-override unicode-bidi="embed" direction="rtl">
        <fo:inline>שלום</fo:inline>
        <fo:footnote>
            <fo:inline alignment-baseline="hanging">1</fo:inline>
            <fo:footnote-body>
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:bidi-override unicode-bidi="embed" direction="rtl">
                        <fo:inline>שלום</fo:inline>
                    </fo:bidi-override>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:footnote-body>
        </fo:footnote>
        <fo:inline>.</fo:inline>
    </fo:bidi-override>
</fo:block>
```

For some reason, the footnote text (at the bottom of the page) appears reverted:

[image]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: FWIW, I tried your FO with AH Formatter, and the footnote text came out in the reverse order from what you show. So it looks like this could be a FOP bug.  Also FWIW, the `fo:inline` in your sample is redundant.

Comment: Thanks! I created an issue. In the meantime, is there a way to mimic the footnote without using XSL-FO <footnote>? Like having the text appear in the footer?

Answer (score 0):

1. (bad) Solution approach: remove (the inner) `direction="rtl"` attribute, but this will probably "break other things".
2. (better) approach (but maybe not readable/funny in your language, sry, when):

   ```
   <fo:inline>םולש</fo:inline>
   ```

..but most confusion (for me & maybe "the engine") raise the nested `<fo:bidi-override/>` elements...

3. approach 'd be:

   ```
   <fo:block text-align="right">
     <fo:bidi-override unicode-bidi="embed" direction="rtl">
       <fo:inline>שלום</fo:inline>
     </fo:bidi-override>
     <fo:footnote>
       <fo:inline alignment-baseline="hanging">1</fo:inline>
       <fo:footnote-body>
         <fo:block>
           <fo:bidi-override unicode-bidi="embed" direction="rtl">
             <fo:inline>שלום</fo:inline>
           </fo:bidi-override>
         </fo:block>
       </fo:footnote-body>
     </fo:footnote>
     <fo:inline>.</fo:inline>
   </fo:block>
   ```

(re-arrange the outer `<fo:bidi-override/>`.)